# MFC. Multiple object of CButton class with different handlers

Tags: c++, windows, class, inheritance, mfc

How to properly use objects of an inherited class, for example the CButton class?

When I use a simple button, I can use its own  **OnBnClickedButtonXXX()** method where I can write whatever I want. And everything that I wrote there will concern only this  **XXX** button.
But in my case I am creating one button class that inherited from CButton class (**CButtonHold**) because of **OnLButtonDown** and **OnLButtonUp** methods, and I want to use it for several buttons with different purpose. How can I to make up my own method something like **OnLButtonDownXXX()** for **CButtonHold** class where I can describe the behavior of specific button **XXX** when I press it and when I release it?

For example this is how I managed to make it: I want to call its own async method **AfxBeginThread** with different parameters when **OnLButtonDown** called and stop threads when **OnLButtonUp** called. This buttons will drive the stepper motors and I need to send different parameters to each button. This simple structure of my program:

Globally I initialize two thread flags:

```
bool thrdOne = true, thrdTwo = true;
CWinThread* motorThread;
```

In class iplementation:

```
class CButtonHold : public CButton
{
    public:
    CButtonHold(int val, bool thrd);
    bool thrd;
    int val;
    ...
}
```

In dialog constructor I init my CButton objects (stupid but work). It makes my CButtons unique:

```
CButtonHold btnX(1, thrdOne), btnY(2, thrdTwo);
```

In dialog class:

```
static UINT btnStartThread(LPVOID arg)
{
    CButtonHold* button = (CButtonHold*)arg;

    while (button->btnThread)
    {
        if(button->val == 1) //doing something....
        else //doing something else....
    }

    AfxEndThread(0, TRUE);
    return 0;
}

void callThread(CButtonHold* button)
{
    if (button->btnThread)
        motorThread = AfxBeginThread(btnStartThread, button, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0, NULL);
} 

void stopThread(CButtonHold* button)
{
    button->btnThread = false;
}
```

Is it normal to write such nonsense or are there more elegant ways to work with specific objects of the same class? This works but I feel something wrong. My question has a bad example but I hope you will get it what is the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Well for one I would decouple all MFC stuff from business logic written in native C++.
Then at least you can ust std::thread and pass it lambda functions with captures. It is a good practice to seperate business logic from the actual UI code anyway, since it makes your business logic unit testable without needing to run the UI in the first place.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, you right, the second part of question is unreasonable and requires improvement, but first part is a pure MFC.

Comment: Can't really help you with MFC it's been 15 years since I used it last. And the be honest I don't really miss it ;)

Comment: If you need your code to behave differently based on a predicate, that predicate needs to be available at the point where you decide what to do. You can encode said predicate either by value or by type. The code presented opted for values. Since those values are compile-time constants, you could go the other route and turn your class into a class template. I'm not confident I understand the problem, which seems to be getting lost in between the idea that asynchronicity mandates multithreading and the actual problem.

Comment: @IInspectable my question primarily concerned inherited classes and the principles of using objects of these classes in MFS. First of all the CButton class. Please ignore the multi-threaded code - this example is out of place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the correct way to create and use descendant classes of MFC controls. You should instead take the following steps:

- Define your own control class (`CButtonHold`, derived from `CButton`). You already did this.
- In VS, open your dialog resource, run the Class Wizard and add member variables to your dialog class. They must be of type "control", not "value". The Wizard will add `DDX_Control()` calls in the `DoDataExchange()` function of your dialog class. This binds the member variables to the actual Win32 controls and additionaly "subclasses" the controls. You shouldn't create the objects yourself (of course, remove those custom constructors).
- Your new control class may contain additional members, like those `thrd` and `val` variables. To perform additional initialization, like passing `thrd` and `val` to the control class you can add a new member function and call it in the dialog's `OnInitDialog()` (overridden) implementation.

The control class must contain the declaration and definition of the `OnLButtonDown()` and `OnLButtonUp()` handlers.

Comment: A custom control class can very well have custom constructors. Instances just need to be constructed from the parent's constructor (typically through a member initializer list). Postponing initialization until the `OnInitDialog` callback runs may well be too late.

Comment: @IInspectable, Of course any class, incl control classes can have multiple constructors, but my point was how to integrate it in a somewhat "standardized" manner, typical of MFC. The code is Wizard-generated and -maintained, and the Wizard won't call the custom constructor. And `OnInitDialog()` is usually fine, as at that point both the actual Win32 controls and the C++ class instances are created and bound together.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to send your own `WM_COMMAND` or notification messages from the `CButtonHold` class to the parent of the button window.

Usually in the UI the parent dialog/window reacts on the actions to a control and decides what to happen upon what button is clicked.